# html 5 help. Render options withing dynamic javascript from websql database

Tags: javascript

In my below function, I render a selectbox. I'm not sure how to pull the options from a database code wise that will integrate into the existing code... thanks.

```
function renderDrinks_Mixer(menucat2)
{
  $('#tblDrink').empty();
  db.transaction(function(tx) 
    {        
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Menu where f_objmenucat2="'+ menucat2 +'"', [],         
        function(tx, results) 
        {            
            var len = results.rows.length, i;                                
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {                                                                                 

            var len = results.rows.length, i;                                
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {                         
              $('#tblDrink').append('<tr class="simpleCart_shelfItem">'

              +'<td class="pcont"><span class="item_category" style="display:none">'+ results.rows.item(i).category +'</span><h3><span class="item_name">'+ results.rows.item(i).drinkname +'</span></h3>'
              +'<p>'+ results.rows.item(i).desc +'</p></td>'
              +'<td align="center" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0">'
              +'<select data-theme="f" name="'+ results.rows.item(i).drinkname +'" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="Plus" data-native-menu="true" id="stringselect">'

                  //#### HELP HERE -PULL OPTIONS FROM DB, NOT SURE HOW TO INTEGRATE ####/

                    +'</select>'
              +'</td>'
             +'</tr>').trigger('create');             
            }                                
          }                    
        }
        , null);                                
    }
    );


}
```

Comment: Any reason for the embedded `for` loop?

Comment: Just keep in mind that Web SQL is deprecated. Use Local Storage or IndexedDB.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably need `$.post()`. You should create some **JSON endpoint** (script that will return data in JSON format) and query it each time you want to retrieve desired data for your list.

For e.g.:

```
$.post("json_endpoint.php", { someParameter: 'and_its_value' },
   function(data){ // requestReady handler
     // do whatever you need with retrieved data.
     // here you can do some logic for enumerating list items from object retrieved from your endpoint
   }
);
```

This way you can easily integrate it and support in the future as a separate script, database logic will be separated from the JS workflow. JS workflow will be only dependent on the data that endpoint returns.

Comment: hmmm thanks for that. web sql is such a life saver! A bit disappointed to hear it could loose support in the future. Does indexdb have sql support?

Comment: @user1215923, look, as long as it is `JavaScript` and **ClientSide** you are writing your `SQL` and **it is open**. It can be of security issue bec. you are discovering yourself. You can do the same with your own endpoint (proposed in answer) and you will be less vulnerable. Unless you care about your own security level.

Comment: right now it's just a proof of concept so not to worried about security as it will be re-written... thanks for the feedback!